# how can assign left of div to left of screen when margin set to auto?

Tags: html, css, screen, center, element

for example i created a div like this

```
<div class="baseDiv" ></div>
```

and css code is :

```
.baseDiv {
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    display:block;  
    margin-top:-10px;
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#039;
}
```

I set div to center of page and left of div fit to left of screen but there is a gap (about 20px) every time, how can remove gap between left of div and left of screen?

Thanks

Comment: padding don't work :/

Comment: margin 0 auto makes no sense if you have width of 100%;

Comment: margin just for sure that div assign to center of screen

Comment: Do you know about chrome dev tools. u can use it to find out where the problem is comlng from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use basic css like

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've most likely still got to update your html and body css.

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a problem. Most browsers have a margin of 8px applied to the body. That is most likely the issue here. To be sure I've added html to the selector and also specified padding be set to 0 as well. 
Using the universal selector (*) applies to all the elements on the page.

Comment: sorry, just i didn't saw your answer and so i accepted @Shailesh Patel answer, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Have a css reset everytime you start with your css and you will avoid many such similar issues: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```